# Where am I wrong with this derivative?

Tags: derivatives

I want to derivate this function :
$$f(t) = \frac{3}{\sin(t)}$$
I know that the derivative of $\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$is$\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^{2}}$ in general and that in this fraction :
$$u'(t) = 0$$
$$v'(t) = \cos(t)$$
So I do :
$$\frac{0\times sin(t)-0\times cos(t)}{\sin(t)^{2}} = 0$$
But Wolfram Alpha gives me another result :
[image]

Comment: your $u$ term is $3$ not $0$.

Comment: @James Oh thank you !

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{u'v-\color{red}{u}v'}{v^{2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

There's an error somewhere in your calculations

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac {3}{\sin(t)} \right) = \frac {\frac{d}{dt}3 \sin(t)-3\frac{d}{dt}\sin(t)}{\sin^2(t)} = \frac {0 \sin(t)-3\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)} = -\frac {3cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}
$$

Comment: Did you made an error ? I wrote $\frac{3\cos(t)}{\sin^{2}(t)}$ and I thought it was $\frac{-3\cos(t)}{\sin^{2}(t)}$

Comment: Because in the formula of the lesson it's a subtraction, not an addition...

Comment: Yours too. $$\frac {\frac{d}{dt}(3) \sin(t)\color{red}{-}3\frac{d}{dt}\sin(t)}{\sin^2(t)}$$

Comment: Yeah, it was supposed to be $-$. Thanks for bringing it to my attention, both of you.